# Why is JavaScript passing into a parameter the source code text?

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/JonnyD/H2Dpe/3/

**Console log:**

```
   [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
     (index):104

   function (newFeedItems) {
       console.log(feedItems);
   } (index):113

   Uncaught TypeError: Object function (newFeedItems) {
      console.log(feedItems);
   } has no method 'sort'
```

Where is it getting this from?

```
function (newFeedItems) {
    console.log(feedItems);
} (index):113
```

when it's supposed to be:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Take a look at the functions `fetchFeeds()` and `processLatestFeed()`. The problem starts at `processLatestFeed(function(newFeedItems) {`

```
function fetchFeeds() {
    fetchVideos(function(newVideoItems) {
        fetchPodcasts(function(newPodcastItems) {
            var newFeedItems = newVideoItems.concat(newPodcastItems);
            console.log(newFeedItems);
            processLatestFeed(function(newFeedItems) {
                console.log(feedItems);
            });
        });
    });
}

function processLatestFeed(newFeedItems, callback) {
    console.log(newFeedItems);
    newFeedItems.sort(function(a,b) {return (a.date > b.date) ? -1 : ((b.date > a.date) ? 1 : 0);});

    for (i in newFeedItems) {
        var newItem = newFeedItems[i];

        if (!isItemInFeed(newItem)) {
            feedItems.push(newItem);
        }

        if (feedItems.length == 50) {
            break;   
        }
    }

    callback();
}
```

Comment: Can you describe your questions further please? I don't think I understand properly what you're trying to say

Comment: @ZachSaucier see newFeedItems and how it is logged to the console, you can see how it correctly displays that it's an array of objects [Object, Object, Object....] however when newFeedItems get passed into processLatestFeed(function(newFeedItems)... it doesn't seem to pass in as an array of object but as source code itself (see the second part of the console log).

Comment: Not sure If I understood, but change this:
            processLatestFeed(newFeedItems, function(){
                console.log(feedItems);
            });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a function as first argument to `processLatestFeed`:

```
processLatestFeed(function(newFeedItems) {
  console.log(feedItems);
});
```

but you defined that function to accept an *array* as first argument and the callback as *second* argument:

```
function processLatestFeed(newFeedItems, callback) {
    console.log(newFeedItems); // <- this logs the function source
    // ...
}
```

So you have to call the function as

```
processLatestFeed(newFeedItems, function() {
  // you are not passing an arguments to the callback
});
```

Comment: im an idiot! been playing around with JavaScript all day - think this my cue to take a break :)

Comment: Yep, that often helps :)